# parse jsonData to get graph

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm working on a project that I have to display 2 different graphs using a dropdown menu. The 2 different graphs are: 
- Live data
- json imported data

I got the first one done, and I got the dropdown menu that changes display done. 
But I don't know how to import jsonData and plot it.
I'm very new to javascript, react and json. 
My teammate told me the current jsonData file looks like this

```
{
    "data": [
        {"datetime": "", "data": [1,2,3,4]},
        {"datetime": "", "data": [1,2,3,4]}
    ]
}
```

I don't understand the format.

The constructor looks

```
   this.state = {
        data: [],
        jsonData: [1,2,3,4]
    }
```

And he gave me a hint on the code that reads:

```
// parse jsonData and set this.state.jsonData to the formated version of the jsonData
```

I don't understand what's going on. I appreciate any help!

I'm not a frequent on stackoverflow so if I can do something to make my posts better, please let me know!

Below is the `Graph.js` that plot the graphs:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import {
  HighchartsChart, Chart, withHighcharts, XAxis, YAxis, Title, Legend, LineSeries
} from 'react-jsx-highcharts';
import './Graph.css'
//import jsonData from '../jsonData.json';

var jsonData = require('../jsonData.json')

class Graph extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.addDataPoint = this.addDataPoint.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    const now = Date.now();

    this.state = {
        data: [],
        jsonData: [1,2,3,4]
    }
}

componentDidMount() {

  // parse jsonData and set this.state.jsonData to the formated version of the jsonData


  console.log(jsonData)

    var sensorSerial = this.props.match.params.sensorId

    const socket = socketIOClient("http://localhost:5001/test");
    socket.on("newnumber", data => this.addDataPoint(data));
  }


  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

  addDataPoint(data){

    console.log(data)

    if(data.sensorSerial == this.props.match.params.sensorId){
      var newData = this.state.data.slice(0)

      console.log(new Date(data.dateTime.split(' ').join('T')))
      //console.log(data.dateTime)
      newData.push([new Date(data.dateTime.split(' ').join('T')), data.number])

      // if(newData.length > 50){
      //   newData.shift()
      // }

      this.setState({
        data: newData
      })
    }
  }

  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }


  render() {

    console.log("calling render()")

    var data = this.state.data

    if(this.state.value === 'processed'){
      var data = this.state.jsonData
    }

    const plotOptions = {
      series: {
        pointStart: new Date("2019-04-04T10:55:08.841287Z")
      }
    }

    return (

      <div className="container">

        <div className="graph">

          <HighchartsChart plotOptions={plotOptions}>
            <Chart />

            <Title>Sensor Data</Title>

            <Legend layout="vertical" align="right" verticalAlign="middle" >
              <Legend.Title>Legend</Legend.Title>
            </Legend>

            <XAxis type="datetime">
              <XAxis.Title>Time</XAxis.Title>
            </XAxis>

            <YAxis>
              <YAxis.Title>Y-axis</YAxis.Title>
              <LineSeries name="Channel 1" data={data}/>
            </YAxis>
          </HighchartsChart>
        </div>


    <div className="side">  
      <div className="SideContainer">

          <div className="upSide">
              <h4>Information</h4>
                  <ul>
                      <li>Device:  <b>Light Absorbtion</b></li>
                      <li>Status:  <b>Connected</b></li>
                      <li>Packets: <b>1021/1220</b></li>
                  </ul>
          </div>

          <div className="downSide">
              <form>
                <label>
                  <h4>Options</h4>
                    <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                      <option value="live">Live</option>
                      <option value="raw">Raw</option>
                      <option value="processed">Processed</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
              </form>

              <form>
                <label>
                  <h4>Channel</h4>
                    <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                      <option value="20">20</option>
                      <option value="40">40</option>
                      <option value="80">80</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
              </form>

              <form>
                <label>
                  <h4>Graph View</h4>
                    <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                      <option value="map">Map</option>
                      <option value="timeseries">Time Series</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
              </form>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withHighcharts(Graph, Highcharts);
```

Comment: Your question does not contain sufficient information about your problem. What is input? what is expected output?

Comment: I assume `data: []` contains live data. And if your live data and jsonData has same structure you can do these things: put jsonData to state.data directly or update state.data. If  jsonData is in a file, get the content and parse with `JSON.parse()`. Then, if you wanna put to state directly: `data: jsonData.data` and push live data to that. But if you wanna update state: `this.setState({data: [...this.state.data, ...jsonData.data]})` We can't help you any further with this limited information. If you can update, we can help you.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the vague info.
Yes, the `data: []` contains live data.
So we're taking in data from different devices, and he said the `[1, 2, 3, 4]` 'are the devices.' and I have updated the post with the .js file